# Draw simple line using google maps api js drawing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there is any way to allow user to draw simple line(not polyline) using google maps js api. I'm tried to do this using polyline, but didn't find any normal ways to make this staff, since polyline drawing will stop only after closing endwith the start of one. At drawing i mean draw like circle or polyline...

Comment: Define 'normal'.  Polyline's are fairly standard when it comes to Google Maps.  You can also use the Drawing library, e.g. see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Comment: I'm need to draw line, which have only one start and one end, but this can't be done with polyline.

Comment: I already used this example and it's worked to create simple line only using two lat lng ( without closing the line). https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?csw=1#try-it-yourself

Comment: I mean to allow user to draw on map

Comment: polygons are closed.  Polylines are not (per se) closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>#map_canvas {height: 400px;}</style>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<p>Click on the map to draw lines</p>

<script>
var polyLines = [];
var markers = [];  // marker objects
var map;

function initMap() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 4.5);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: myCenter
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // detect click on the map.  

  var startPoint = null;
  var endPoint = null;
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latLng.lat();
    var lng = e.latLng.lng();
    var position = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
    if(! startPoint) {
      startPoint = position;
    }
    else if(! endPoint) {
      endPoint = position;
      // so now we draw a line
      var polyLine = makePolyline([startPoint, endPoint]);
      polyLines.push(polyLine);
      // reset the points
      startPoint = null;
      endPoint = null;
    }
  });
}

// return a polyline.   If you give 2 points, it will simply be a line
function makePolyline(points) {
  return new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: points,
    // geodesic: true,     // this makes the line curvy
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
}

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it can be don via connecting two points, but it will not have drawing effect

Comment: How about you describe what you need, a little better

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing cannot be done using the Google Maps Drawing API. However, you can achieve this using a JavaScript canvas. You can modify the example here, which is for letting users draw rectangles.

[Let users draw rectangles with mouse in canvas with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376480/let-users-draw-rectangles-with-mouse-in-canvas-with-javascript)